# Echart : How to have a transparent brush on a darker chart

Tags: charts, echarts, brush

On Echart, I am using a brush mode to select some area on the chart. The brush selection has a color which is configurable. I would like to know if it's possible to make the brush selection transparent and darken the part of the chart which is not sectioned.

The result should look like that : (the highlighted part is the part sectioned with the brush mode)

[image]